# Condensed / pyknotic approach to orbifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, orbifolds, condensed-mathematics

Does [condensed / pyknotic mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/condensed+set) afford an (yet!) another approach to orbifold theory?

Let me admit up-front that I don't know much about either condensed / pyknotic mathematics or about orbifold theory. But I think the following is a precise question which gets at the the above vague question.

I believe there are several approaches to defining what an orbifold is, so for safety let me restrict attention to the $(2,1)$-category $\mathcal C$ of *topological* orbifolds $X$ such that $X$ is the orbifold quotient of a topological manifold $X_0$ by a properly discontinuous group action. I hope that even if there are differences between definitions of topological orbifolds, they should all at least agree on the category $\mathcal C$ up to equivalence of $(2,1)$-categories.

On the other hand, every compactly generated weak Hausdorff space, and in particular every topological manifold, may be regarded as a condensed set in a canonical way. Moreover, there inclusion functor $Set \to Gpd$ induces an inclusion functor $Cond(Set) \to Cond(Gpd)$ from condensed sets to condensed groupoids. Let $\mathcal D$ be the full, $(2,1)$-subcategory of $Cond(Gpd)$ whose objects are $(2,1)$-categorical quotients of topological manifolds by properly discontinuous group actions.

There are canonical inclusion functors $Man \to \mathcal C$ and $Man \to \mathcal D$ where $Man$ is the category of topological manifolds (where every 2-morphism is the identity).

**Question:** Is there an equivalence of $(2,1)$-categories $\mathcal C \simeq \mathcal D$ respecting the two inclusions $Man \rightrightarrows \mathcal C, \mathcal D$?

Comment: Condense the orbs, Man!

Comment: What is the notion of morphism of orbifold that you had in mind? And what is the definition of a 2-arrow between such? I only know of the work of Pronk et al that really digs into this using topological groupoids (building on Moerdijk, surveyed by Lerman etc etc), and more recent work of Schreiber via global homotopy theory.

Comment: @DavidRoberts To be honest I don't know what the correct notion of morphism of orbifolds is. I was assuming that in the case of topological quotient orbifolds, the choice of morphisms should be unambiguous. If there are important differences even here I will have to do more research to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Personally, I would just say that the appropriate 2-category of topological stacks with a presentation by a proper étale groupoid (maybe with effectivity thrown in). But there are people who want to use diffeological spaces and *not* groupoids, where the 2-arrows are invisible. And then there is the traditional Satake–Thurston version, where none of this higher stuff is even thought of. And then there is https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Proper+Orbifold+Cohomology

Comment: @DavidRoberts I've attempted to avoid subtleties about which objects are included in the category by restricting to topological quotient orbifolds, but if it's still unclear which of those to include, I'm happy to be as restrictive as is possible for now. I've no doubt the original approaches to orbifolds didn't think to define a 2-categorical structure, but my hope is that from a modern perspective, at least on the simplest possible orbifolds, there's a unique reasonable notion of map which restricts to "continuous map" on topological manifolds and a unique reasonable notion of 2-morphism.

Comment: Well, start with the maps between the corresponding topological stacks, that's at least a standard approach. It's not so much about picking the nice objects, you might as well take all action groupoids with proper action that is almost free, not just those involving discrete groups.

Comment: @DavidRoberts (Thanks for all the help, btw!) I think I want to restrict to discrete groups (at least for now) because on the condensed side, I want to use discrete groupoids to model the "stacky direction" of things (thinking of them as 1-truncated homotopy types of course). In order to allow more complicated groups, I'd have to think about how to take into account their non-discrete nature on the condensed side. For now I want to keep things simple and just work with condensed groupoids on that side of things.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I hope it was clarifying, and not a firehose of random nonsense. It's a good question, btw.

Comment: Might be nice to link to a definition of "condensed set" or "pyknotic mathematics." I don't know these terms, but I'm interested in orbifolds and most other things you are interested in.

Comment: @DavidWhite I added an nlab link. A condensed / pyknotic object in a (potentially higher) category $\mathcal C$ is a $\mathcal C$-valued sheaf on the (large) site of compact Hausdorff spaces (or on some dense subsite like profinite sets or spaces of ultrafilters, where the sheaf condition simplifies to preservation of finite products). You have to deal with the largeness of the site set-theoretically; the difference is condensed vs. pyknotic. The idea is to make everything in sight have a topology (just as $\infty$-categories make everything in sight have an $\infty$-groupoid structure).

Comment: Actually, if topological orbifolds are certain stacks of groupoids on the site of topological manifolds, and condensed groupoids are stacks of groupoids on compact Hausdorff spaces, then it seems likely that the answer to my question in the very restricted form I've given it should be an easy "yes".

Comment: I think the only subtlety is whether $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Cond}$ is a morphism between sites in a suitable way. For example, is every cover of a topological manifold in $\mathbf{Cond}$ refined by an open cover by topological spaces? Or by an open cover by topological manifolds?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think you're right -- there are issues. The topology on compact Hausdorff spaces used for condensed sets is the canonical topology, where a cover is just any finite jointly surjective family of maps. Whereas even for topological orbifolds, one will be considering covers by families of open embeddings. I think the answer to the question is probably "no". So this simple-minded approach to condensing the orbs seems to fail.

Comment: https://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-06-07/thumbnail-leaders-touching-orb/8597444?nw=0

Comment: Since notions of cohesion (infinitesimal, differential, singular) can all be understood relative to an arbitrary base ∞-topos, what happens when forming infinity-sheaves of pyknotic ∞-groupoids over the 2-site they call Singularities on p.58 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01101?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Great question! I think the answer ought to be yes. But I must also make a disclaimer that I don't really know what orbifolds are, and the comments by David Roberts make be believe that what I thought they should be is not what they actually are.

To me, an orbifold should be to a manifold as a Deligne--Mumford stack is to a scheme. In particular, they should naturally form a $2$-category (just like groupoids do). Recall that a Deligne--Mumford stack is a stack (=sheaf of groupoids) $X$ on the category of schemes equipped with the étale topology such that there is a surjective étale map $Y\to X$ from a scheme $Y$. Now the most general definition of an étale map of stacks is actually a bit subtle. Let me only consider the case of $0$-truncated maps (which is the only case relevant here, as $Y$ and thus $Y\to X$ is $0$-truncated). The case of separated étale maps is OK: A map $f: Y\to X$ is separated étale if and only if for all maps $X'\to X$ from a scheme $X'$, the fibre product $Y'=Y\times_X X'$ is representable by a scheme, and $Y'\to X'$ is separated étale. To verify that this is a good definition, one uses that separated étale maps of schemes satisfy fpqc descent. For general étale maps, one has to iterate this procedure a bit: One should only ask that $Y'$ is an algebraic space, and $Y'\to X'$ an étale map of algebraic spaces. To define the latter, one takes an étale cover of $Y'$ and asks that the composite map to $X$ is étale.

Now the translation to (topological, say) manifolds is somewhat complicated by the fact that separatedness assumptions are much more commonly assumed by default. For example, I think $\mathbb R$ with a doubled origin (i.e. two copies of $\mathbb R$ glued along $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$) does not count as a topological manifold, even while its algebraic analogue has long become a honorable member of the category of schemes. I will thus assume that the "correct" notion of orbifold is the one one obtains by pretending that all schemes are separated, and all étale maps are separated étale. One then gets the following notion.

Consider the category of topological manifolds $\mathrm{Man}$, and make it into a site by using open covers as covers. Then an orbifold is a stack (=sheaf of groupoids) $X$ on $\mathrm{Man}$ such that there is a surjective separated étale map $Y\to X$ for some manifold $Y$. Here, a map $Y\to X$ of stacks on $\mathrm{Man}$ is separated étale if after pullback $X'\to X$ from any manifold $X'$, the fibre product $Y'=Y\times_X X'\to X'$, $Y'$ is a manifold, and $Y'\to X'$ is a local isomorphism.

Here is a different way to proceed, starting from condensed groupoids. Recall that these are sheaves of groupoids on the site $\mathrm{ProFin}$ of profinite sets, with covers given by finite families of jointly surjective maps. Again, we first define separated étale maps $f: Y\to X$ of condensed groupoids: This means that after any pullback $S\to X$ to a profinite set $S$, the fibre product $Y\times_X S$ is representable by a locally profinite set, and the map to $S$ is a local isomorphism. Any manifold $M$ defines a condensed set $\underline{M}$ via sending $S$ to the set of continuous maps from $S$ to $M$, and this embeds manifolds fully faithfully into condensed sets. Now one can define an orbifold to be a condensed groupoid $X$ that admits a surjective separated étale map $\underline{M}\to X$ from the condensed set corresponding to a manifold $M$.

We claim that these definitions are equivalent. First, there is a functor: Any orbifold $X$ in the condensed sense defines a sheaf of groupoids on $\mathrm{Man}$ by sending $M$ to the groupoid of maps $\underline{M}\to X$.

> Proposition. This functor is an equivalence of categories.

Let me just explain the key step. Assume that $M$ is a topological manifold, and $f: Y\to \underline{M}$ is a separated étale map of condensed sets. Then $Y=\underline{N}$ for some manifold $N$, where $N\to M$ is a local isomorphism. To prove this, the idea is the following. Take any $y\in Y$ mapping to $m\in M$. We want to find a neighborhood of $y$ mapping isomorphically to a neighborhood of $m$. But for separated étale maps, sections always extend from closed subsets (like $\{m\}\subset M$) to small strict neighborhoods (and uniquely so, up to further shrinking the neighborhood). By descent, this can be checked after taking surjections from profinite sets to closed neighborhoods, and after pullback to profinite sets, the claim is easy to see.

Let me also advertise that in [Etale cohomology of diamonds](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/EtCohDiamonds.pdf), I'm very much proceeding along such lines to define various "geometric objects" in $p$-adic geometry akin to (pretty wild forms of) orbifolds, by essentially adopting the condensed point of view (but this paper predates the introduction of the "condensed" term). In that paper, the role of profinite sets is played by "strictly totally disconnected perfectoid spaces", which are essentially profinite sets of geometric points. The difference here is that there is not just one kind of geometric point, but rather one for any complete algebraically closed nonarchimedean field $C$ (of characteristic $p$). One then studies all geometric objects by regarding them as quotients of (disjoint unions of) such strictly totally disconnected perfectoid spaces. The analogue of the key step is Lemma 15.6 (or really Lemma 11.31) there, comparing étale maps defined via descent to strictly totally disconnected spaces to étale maps defined more geometrically. That it was possible to develop the whole machinery from this point of view of descent to strictly totally disconnected spaces is what convinced me personally that it's not a completely crazy idea to regard manifolds as quotients of locally profinite sets.

Comment: Thanks, this is very edifying! And it's a relief to see one can jump straight to a full answer, rather than having to restrict attention to simple cases as I tried to do. I was thinking that the "open embedding" concept inherent in the Grothendieck topology on $Man$ would be hard to honor condensedly. But I see you've imported it via the notion of "open embedding from a condensed set $U$ to a profinite set $X$" (meaning that $U \to X$ is just an open embedding of profinite sets), implicit in "locally profinite" and "local isomorphism" which appear in the definition of "separated etale". Neat!

Comment: I'm curious whether the same definitions and arguments work verbatim if we replace the words "profinite set" everywhere with one of the equivalent sites -- "compact Hausdorff space", "Stonean space", or "space of ultrafilters". Incidentally, is there a general definition of "open embedding of condensed sets"? I suppose it would just be "map $Y \to X$ such that $Y \times_X S \to S$ is an open emedding for every map $S \to X$ from a profinite set"...

Comment: You can replace "profinite set" everywhere with these other words, as in fact follows from the proof of the key fact. And yes, there is such a general definition of an open embedding of condensed sets. In a slightly different direction, one can in fact even define a nice general class of "etale" maps of condensed animae, asking that the map is "relatively discrete".

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Regarding etale maps of condensed anima/animae, I think this is one one of those places where I'm confused by the two competing notions of "discrete". My best guess at the notion of "etale map $Y \to X$" you have in mind is one where, for any profinite set $S$ and map $S \to X$, the object $Y \times_X S \in Cond(An)_{/S}$ is locally constant in that almost-$\infty$-topos, even though that definition doesn't use the notion of open embedding between profinite sets.

Comment: The definition should be that it lies in the essential image of the fully faithful functor from sheaves of animae on the profinite $S$ (with its usual open cover topology), to sheaves of animae on $\mathrm{Cond}_{/S}$. So it's discrete, not $0$-truncated.

Comment: What do étale maps $Y\to X$ mentioned above look like when $X$ is given by a compact Hausdorff space? Does that coincide with covering spaces in topology?

Comment: They are just local isomorphisms, the proof is the same as for manifolds. "Covering space" would be stronger -- open immersions are etale, but not covering spaces.

Comment: OK, thanks. You meant the equivalence between sheaves and their étalé spaces. Is the fully faithful functor that you mentioned above closely related to Lurie's identification of sheaves on a compactum $X$ and "left ultrafunctors" (of which I have not yet unrolled the definitions) from $X$ to sets?