# Local isomorphism of condensed sets and étale condensed groupoids

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, topos-theory, condensed-mathematics

Is there a notion of local isomorphism for condensed sets?

$\textbf{Motivation:}$ I am trying to define what an étale condensed groupoid would be.

A topological groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ is said to be étale if the source map, $s : \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{G}) \to \mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{G})$, is a local homeomorphism. I surmise that the appropriate way to define an étale condensed groupoid would be to replace "topological" with "condensed" and "local homeomorphism" with "local isomorphism". Is this the correct approach?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Here, condensed groupoid means a [groupoid object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid+object) in the category of condensed sets.

In this MO [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384099/condensed-pyknotic-approach-to-orbifolds), in Professor Scholze's answer, he talks about such property. To cite him:

> Here is a different way to proceed, starting from condensed groupoids. Recall that these are sheaves of groupoids on the site $\mathrm{ProFin}$ of profinite sets, with covers given by finite families of jointly surjective maps. Again, we first define separated étale maps $f: Y\to X$ of condensed groupoids: This means that after any pullback $S\to X$ to a profinite set $S$, the fibre product $Y\times_X S$ is representable by a locally profinite set, and the map to $S$ is a local isomorphism.

Comment: If there is a notion of openness for maps of condensed sets, then you could copy the characterisation of local homeomorphism as "open + open relative diagonal". But that is treating "local" as somehow based on open subspaces, which is not necessarily the right idea.

Comment: There's an interesting subtlety in the equivalence between "open with open diagonal" and "local homeomorphism". To prove this you need to know what open subspaces of the cartesian product are. If there are more open subspaces than just unions of rectangles then the equivalence fails. This is why the algebraic geometry analogue "flat with flat diagonal" is not equivalent to "Zariski-local isomorphism". (It is equivalent to "étale".)

Comment: The point of the étaleness of the source and target maps of a topological étale groupoid is not that the maps themselves have that specific property; rather that one can prove things about other objects built from that groupoid (or categories of them). And these things are probably what one wants from condensed groupoids, in the end, too.

Comment: Interesting! But I am not aware of a notion o openness for condensed morphisms.

Comment: As you note, Scholze gave one possible definition of local homeomorphism, namely a morphism of condensed sets representable by local homeomorphisms \[Tag [0023](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0023)\] (where a transformation $a \colon F \to G$ is representable *by morphisms with some property $\mathcal P$* if for all $h_V = h_U \times_G F \to h_U$ as in that tag, the map $V \to U$ has property $\mathcal P$). So it is unclear to me what your precise question is — is this definition not adequate for your purposes?

Comment: In the text I cited he just defines separated étale maps of condensed groupoids and not local isomorphism. He just mentions in the end that the map $S\to X$ is a local isomorphism.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by étale, but in topology, isn't that the same thing as a local isomorphism? Then the only difference is whether it is separated, which Scholze probably forgot to say in the last sentence of the quoted passage.

Comment: Oh, ok! I didn't know that this two concepts were synonym. Thank you!